# copy lines into new file except specific line from text file in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to copy data from textfile1 to a new textfile (textfile2). but there's a specific line that i wish to exclude. i found a way to get the line where data i want to exclude is from.

What i'm doing here is that i'm checking if "testfile.txt" contains the string inputted by the user from textbox1. if the file does contain said input, it would then check if that same input is also available in "textfile1".

```
string old = @"textfile1.txt";
string new = @"textfile2.txt";
string test = @"testfile.txt";

string[] line = File.ReadAllLines(test);
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    if (line[i].Contains(textbox1.Text))
    {   
        string fileData = File.ReadAllText(path);
        for (int n = 0; n < line.Length; n++)
        {
            if (line[n].Contains(textbox1.Text))
            {
                n++; //gets line number
                
                //other code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now what i want to do is to copy everything in that textfile1 except the line wherein the inputted data was found.

**SAMPLE DATA**

*textfile1.txt* (id,item,price)

> 0001,apple,5
>
> 0002,banana,3
>
> 0003,mango,6

*user inputs `0002` in textbox1*

**SUPPOSED OUTPUT**

*textfile2.txt*

> 0001,apple,5
>
> 0003,mango,6

*"why not just delete that line from the file?"* well, i tried but yeah i'm having troubles with is too so i tried doing this instead.

I've been trying all sorts of things but i can't seem to make anything work :( any suggestions? any form of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got too many loops. You should be able to do it in one:

```
string oldFile = @"textfile1.txt";
string newFile = @"textfile2.txt";
string test = @"testfile.txt";

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(oldFile);

using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(newFile))
{
    foreach(var line in lines) {
        if (!line.Contains(textbox1.Text))
        {
            w.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use LINQ to filter out the lines you don't want, and then write them back out all at once:

```
var newLines = File.ReadLines(oldFile).Where(l => !l.contains(textbox1.Text));
File.WriteAllLines(newFile, newLines);
```