# If string exists in text file then <condition> in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to check if the string exists in a text file and if it does then proceed. if not, it will display a `MessageBox` saying that the ID does not exist.

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611447/copy-lines-into-new-file-except-specific-line-from-text-file-in-c-sharp), I tried to check if `"testfile.txt"` contains the string inputted by the user in `TextBox1` then copy the line which contains the string into a new textfile. Using the approach that has been suggested, here's a snippet of what I have so far:

```
string emp_profile = @"EmployeeData.txt"; //file to be checked
string endata = @"EndData.txt"; //terminated employees data file
string end_tdata = @"end_tdata.txt"; //holds sample's data

//validates if eid exists and if it exists copies data of sample 
//plus txt_end.Text into temporary data file 
string[] dataline = File.ReadAllLines(emp_profile);
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(end_tdata))
{
    foreach (var line in dataline)
    {
        if (line.Contains(txt_un.Text))
        {
            w.WriteLine(txt_end.Text + "," + line);

            w.Close();
        }
    }
}

string end_holddata = @"end_holddata.txt";

//read original file
string[] raw_data = File.ReadAllLines(endata);

using (StreamWriter r = File.AppendText(end_holddata))
{
    foreach (var line in raw_data)
    {
        if (!line.Contains(txt_un.Text))
            r.WriteLine(line);
    }
    r.Close();
}

//delete original file
File.Delete(endata);

//creates new data file with old data path
//and copies the temporary data held testdata
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(end_holddata))
using (Stream output = new FileStream(endata, FileMode.Append,
                                      FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    input.CopyTo(output);
}

//appends new data of sample into the newly created data file
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(end_tdata))
using (Stream output = new FileStream(endata, FileMode.Append,
                                      FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    input.CopyTo(output);
}

DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Data has been recorded.");

//clears all temporary files
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    File.Delete(end_holddata);
    File.Delete(end_tdata);
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is that I'm copying the data from the `"emp_profile.txt` that does not contain the `txt_un.Text` into `"end_holddata"` and copy the line that contains the input into a different file `end_tdata.txt`, delete the old datafile to clear contents then merge the data into a new data with the same pathfile as the old one. Afterwards, the temporary data files would be deleted.

I tried enclosing the above snippet within this but it's not working the way I want it to.

```
string[] dataline = File.ReadAllLines(emp_profile);
for (int i = 0; i < dataline.Length; i++)
{
    if (dataline[i].Contains(txt_un.Text))
    {

        //code snippet here
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("ID does not exist!");
}
```

Any help would appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are closing the stream inside the first loop. You should get an exception if you try to write more than one line

Comment: @Steve I've moved the `w.Close();` after the foreach loop. But when I ran the program, even if the ID does not exist, it still get a `messagebox: data has been recorded` and the dialog box keeps popping up 'til i press the OK button a couple times

Comment: @Steve and if the ID does exist, I get `messagebox: id not found` then the `data has been recorded` after i click on OK then the first dialogbox pops up again